# How do I scale a page too large for the screen?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a webpage that has N DIV elements which end up in a (free flowing) grid.  The resulting webpage is too large for the screen and I want to scale so that the N elements are as large as possible, reflowed as required, but fit the screen.  The DIV elements are not in encompassed by a table or similar element.

I have been using `style.zoom=...` to scale and this sort-of works but not on Firefox so I'm trying to use `style.transform = scale(..,..)` to scale the DIV elements.  The DIV elements do scale, but they remain in the same place seeming to take up as much overall screen space as they did before I shrunk them (they seem to 'gain' a lot of surrounding whitespace), the screen doesn't reflow and things still don't fit the screen.
I've been reading up on transform and am thoroughly confused as to what it is supposed to do if the space taken up on screen remains the same even if the item is shrunk!

I want to see all my elements, shrunk to fit the screen and reflowed with no 'big white space' around them.  Is this possible?

Comment: Please see how to create [mcve]

Comment: You need what it is called 'responsive' design. Try [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) or something similar.

Comment: Yes, this is what a scale transformation does - it keeps the original space the element required before the transformation was applied, reserved.